# Save only those Outlook Email Attachments from Inbox, which are sent by specific sender on specific dates

Tags: excel, vba, search, outlook, office-automation

Hi I have more than 3500 Emails in my OL Inbox. My conditions are.

1. I Want to save all attachments from some specific senders for some specifics dates as per my requirements Using Outlook VBA.

```
Sub Save_OutLook_Attachments_To_Folder()
Dim App As Outlook.Application
Dim MyFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim NS As Outlook.Namespace
Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim Attachments As Outlook.Attachments
Dim Items As Outlook.Items
Dim i As Long
Dim lngCount As Long
Dim File As String
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim Sender_Email As String ''''

Sender_Email = "someone@somewhere.com" '''''''objMail.SenderEmailAddress  ''''''
FolderPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "\Outlook Attachments\" '''Change the Destination Folder Path
Set App = New Outlook.Application
Set NS = App.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set MyFolder = NS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) ''''''''''''
Set Items = MyFolder.Items
Items.Sort Property:="[ReceivedTime]", Descending:=True
FolderPath = FolderPath
For Each Msg In MyFolder.Items
If Msg.SenderEmailAddress = Sender_Email Then '''''
Set Attachments = Msg.Attachments
lngCount = Attachments.Count
End If
Next
If lngCount > 0 Then
For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1
File = Attachments.Item(i).FileName
File = FolderPath & File
Attachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile File
Next
End If
End Sub
```

Would appreciate if anyone can help me in this case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating over all items in the folder and checking the sender-related properties:

```
For Each Msg In MyFolder.Items
  If Msg.SenderEmailAddress = Sender_Email Then '''''
```

Use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class. In that case you will get a collection of items that correspond to the search criteria specified. You can read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Try using the following search criteria:

```
criteria = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:senderemail" & Chr(34) & " LIKE '%" & Sender_Email & "%'"
```

See [Filtering Items Using a String Comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/search-and-filter/filtering-items-using-a-string-comparison) for more information.

---

Note, you can use the logical AND operator in the search string where you can combine multiple conditions. To search items for a specific date you can filter on the `urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived` property. Find the sample code in the following articles:

- [How To: Retrieve Outlook calendar items using Find and FindNext methods](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/11/outlook-retrieve-calendar-items/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method in Outlook to get calendar items](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/15/outlook-restrict-calendar-items/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is code I use to save the attachments from e-mails I have selected. You can probably adapt to your requirements or manually filter and select the emails when you need to.

```
Public Sub SaveAttachmentsSelectedEmails()
    Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim olSelection As Outlook.Selection: Set olSelection = ActiveExplorer.Selection
    Dim FilePath As String: FilePath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\Documents\Attachments"

    If Dir(FilePath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        Debug.Print "Save folder does not exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each olItem In olSelection
        SaveAttachments olItem, FilePath, RemoveAttachments:=False
    Next olItem
End Sub

Private Function SaveAttachments(ByVal Item As Object, FilePath As String, _
    Optional Prefix As String = "", _
    Optional FileExtensions As String = "*", _
    Optional Delimiter As String = ",", _
    Optional RemoveAttachments As Boolean = False, _
    Optional OverwriteFiles As Boolean = False) As Boolean

    On Error GoTo ExitFunction

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, FileName As String, Flag As Boolean
    Dim Extensions() As String: Extensions = Split(FileExtensions, Delimiter)
    If Right(FilePath, 1) <> "\" Then FilePath = FilePath & "\"

    For j = LBound(Extensions) To UBound(Extensions)
        With Item.Attachments
            If .Count > 0 Then
                For i = .Count To 1 Step -1
                    FileName = FilePath & Prefix & .Item(i).FileName
                    Flag = IIf(LCase(Right(FileName, Len(Extensions(j)))) = LCase(Extensions(j)), True, False)
                    Flag = IIf(FileExtensions = "*" Or Flag = True, True, False)
                    If Flag = True Then
                        If Dir(FileName) = "" Or OverwriteFiles = True Then
                            .Item(i).SaveAsFile FileName
                        Else
                            Debug.Print FileName & " already exists"
                            Flag = False
                        End If
                    End If
                    If RemoveAttachments = True And Dir(FileName) <> "" And Flag = True Then .Item(i).Delete
                Next i
            End If
        End With
    Next j
    SaveAttachments = True

ExitFunction:
End Function
```