# Skip meeting request in for each selection loop

Tags: vba, outlook, meeting-request

I am working on a simple Marco that use to download selected emails' attachments.
It was really a simple logic but I am still stuck.

I found out that my for each loop is always stop when it met the meeting request email.
(It almost took my whole day to figure it out that the meeting request is The Barricade.)
The problem can be fixed by deletion of the meeting request.
And yet, it is really annoying for a lazybones like me.

Therefore, I really curious that i**s there any method can let the for each loop just ignore/auto unselect meeting requests**?

And I have already tried detect the email subject/context to seprate the meeting requests and normal mails.
But it seem like it would just exit the for each loop when it encountered the meeting request.

So currently I don't have any idea about how to fixing it.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72717042/3688861

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there any method can let the for each loop just ignore/auto unselect meeting requests?

In the loop you need to check whether the `Class` property equals to the `olMail` value:

```
For x = 1 To Item.Count 
   If Items.Item(x).Class = OlObjectClass.olMail Then 

   End If
Next x
```

For example, here is a sample code which shows how to handle different item types in Outlook:

```
Sub GetSelectedItems() 
 Dim myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer 
 Dim myOlSel As Outlook.Selection 
 Dim mySender As Outlook.AddressEntry 
 Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem 
 Dim oAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem 
 Dim oPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor 
 Dim strSenderID As String 
 Const PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_ENTRYID As String = _ 
 "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x00410102" 
 Dim MsgTxt As String 
 Dim x As Long 
 
 MsgTxt = "Senders of selected items:" 
 Set myOlExp = Application.ActiveExplorer 
 Set myOlSel = myOlExp.Selection 
 For x = 1 To myOlSel.Count 
   If myOlSel.Item(x).Class = OlObjectClass.olMail Then 
     ' For mail item, use the SenderName property. 
     Set oMail = myOlSel.Item(x) 
     MsgTxt = MsgTxt & oMail.SenderName & ";" 
   ElseIf myOlSel.Item(x).Class = OlObjectClass.olAppointment Then 
     ' For appointment item, use the Organizer property. 
     Set oAppt = myOlSel.Item(x) 
     MsgTxt = MsgTxt & oAppt.Organizer & ";" 
   Else 
     ' For other items, use the property accessor to get sender ID, 
     ' then get the address entry to display the sender name. 
     Set oPA = myOlSel.Item(x).PropertyAccessor 
     strSenderID = oPA.GetProperty(PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_ENTRYID) 
     Set mySender = Application.Session.GetAddressEntryFromID(strSenderID) 
     MsgTxt = MsgTxt & mySender.Name & ";" 
   End If 
 Next x 
 
 Debug.Print MsgTxt 

End Sub
```

Remember that Outlook folders may contain different kind of items - mail, appointment, document, note and etc.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to show the relevant snippet of your code.

Secondly, you should not assume that you are only dealing with the `MailItem` objects - before accessing any of the MailItem-specific properties, check that the `Class` property (it is exposed by all OOM objects) is `43` (which is `olMail`).